# How to flash - Management Blade MMB S3 - Fujitsu

Tags: blade-server

I have a BX600 and I need to know how to flash the MMB S3. I have no IP access to the device and I think that there has been an issue with the transfer using TFTPD32 to upgrade the MMB S3.

I have checked the manual and there is nothing about recovering from the process, or I should say the information is very limited.

There is a console port.

The manual can be found here ([Click Here](http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Download/Index.asp))

Industry Standard Servers > PRIMERGY BLADE SERVER > PRIMERGY  BX600 S3 with MMB3 > Management Blade MMB S3

Thank you

Comment: You seriously should consider contacting [Fujitsu phone support](http://webdownload.ts.fujitsu.com/Download/FileDownload/FileDownload.aspx?SoftwareGUID=08601521-B3D7-4D11-9E84-C227E1B9E37E&FileFolder=Datenpool%5CKMT_Customer%5CKMT_Information&FileTypeExtension=PDF&FileNameClient=HelpDeskList_International.PDF). We had a couple of support contacts because of our older BX600 chassis and the tech support engineers always have been helpful and competent.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Not as of yet, however I was using the forums as my first approach. I think it will be a solution via the console port however there is very little documentation online regarding the MMB3.

Comment: If flashing can brick the MMB, there *will* be a recovery procedure for it - the support engineers are the ones to ask first.

Comment: do i need to have a support contract? In this case I do not.

Comment: I never had to call Fujitsu in Spain, but at least in Germany, you don't. Also, your system is rather new and at least the BX600 sold in Germany are covered by a 3-year warranty without the need for an additional support pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for all.

For those who have the same problem. You will need the following:

- The use of terminal
- A null modem cable
- patience
- The latest firmware for you MMB card

What to do!

1. Look online for the manual regarding the terminal access for your BX600
2. connect and push in the null modem cable and you will get some info on screen
3. Make sure you have the BIN file on the desktop
4. Use command "upgradex"
5. right click on the screen and select the file, roughly 30MB, it will transfer at 4k sec
6. Make some tea and toast and relax. This is where I am now. (2 hours and 15 minutes to go!)

I will update once complete.

Thank you

Update 26/07/2012

To make it work. You may have to try this several times not to get a fault with the CRC.

All works now. I have to do it a total of 7 time via serial.